# Core Data with Multiple Background Threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an iphone/ipad app using Core Data.
Data is provided via various web service calls.
I use a polling mechanism to determine when each of the service calls are to be made, independently from one another, in order to keep information up to date.
As such, there may very well be multiple background threads processing data from these calls using multiple MOC's. For insertions and updates, this approach works fine.
In trying to implement delete functionality, my program crashes. It seems to be caused when the context in one thread deletes a managed object that another thread is also working with, because the deleted object has been faulted.

I have been searching for solutions online, but haven't arrived at anything in particular.
Should deletes be pushed on to the main thread's context? What about maintaining a single thread and accompanying MOC in a Singleton for doing all the processing?

Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found it helpful in situations of concurrent access to a set of data, shared between parts of the same application, to use flagging objects as obsolete before actually deleting them.

This makes it more easy to catch requests for obsolete data and to respond appropriately.

Usually I'll have some sort of data manager singleton class which handles all access. The flag may be a timestamp attribute to the entities, marking the last access to the object. Actual deletion of flagged objects happens while no other requests are in queue and if the object has not been used for a certain amount of time.

Depending on the type and amount of data and how frequently changes are made, this approach may need refinement though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I'd have to add a lot of code to manage this type of implementation, but it does sound good.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been searching for solutions online, but haven't arrived at anything in particular.

Have you tried everything that Apple suggests in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1)?  Without seeing your code, it seems to me that the bit you are missing is the [NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW5) part.  Each thread has to register for MOC saves on the other threads.  This implies that the threads must all have a run loop.

On the whole, it all looks a bit messy.  I think I would change the architecture to do all Core Data changes on the main thread (not just delete).

Comment: In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changesSaved:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
<br>
This calls:<br>
- (void)changesSaved:(NSNotification *)note
{
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changesSavedOnMainThread:) withObject:note waitUntilDone:YES];
}
<br>
Finally,<br>
- (void)changesSavedOnMainThread:(NSNotification *)note
{
 if ([note object] != __managedObjectContext) [__managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
}

Comment: Sorry the above comment looks terrible. Anyway, I backgrounded this processing to theoretically keep the main thread as free as possible. I could definitely adjust to see how performance is affected by processing on main thread, vs. backgrounded.